# Best way to fill in data based on another instance of one column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on a dataset that are generally grouped by an ID and we have some missing info. I want to fill in info based on another instance of that ID, and I was hoping to find out the best way to do it. Here's some example data:

```
data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Start": ['11/1/23', '11/2/23', '12/12/23', '12/23/23', '9/4/23', '9/11/23'],
    "End": ['', '11/3/23', '12/13/23', '12/28/23', '','9/18/23']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df

    ID  Start       End
0   1   11/1/23 
1   1   11/2/23     11/3/23
2   2   12/12/23    12/13/23
3   2   12/23/23    12/28/23
4   3   9/4/23  
5   3   9/11/23     9/18/23
```

I'd like it to detect the other ID's start that and apply it to the missing end date. So for instance, row 0's end date would turn to 11/2/23 because that's the same ID's start date on the next line. The data I'm actually working with it thousands of rows long so I'm working to avoid doing this manually.

Here's the intended result:

```
    ID  Start       End
0   1   11/1/23     11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23     11/3/23
2   2   12/12/23    12/13/23
3   2   12/23/23    12/28/23
4   3   9/4/23      9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23     9/18/23
```

Comment: Item 2 and 3 have same `ID` and different `End` how do you decide which one to pick?

Comment: @AjinkyaKamat You don't since there's nothing to fill in.

Comment: Do you mean index 2 and 3? Those have an end date already, so nothing would need to happen to those. This would only apply for if there's a blank end date.

Comment: @E_Sarousi So, you are saying, there is no are cases in your entire thousands of rows where there is a blank date and with `ID` `i` where other items with `ID` `i` have different `end`?

Comment: Correct. Every row I have with an empty end date also has another row with another start date. I'm trying to use that start date to fill into the missing end date.

Comment: In that case, it is simple. Go through you data once and create a `dict` from `(id, start)` to `end`. Only add entries to the map if `end` is not blank. Then go through it again but this time use the map to fill in the blank `end` based on the `dict` you created.

Comment: if you have expected value in next row then you could use `.shift{-1}` to create new column with values moves to previous rows and then in every row you can copy value from new column if you have empty place in current column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variant of @Nick's answer using [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.shift.html) and [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to match the empty strings:

```
df.loc[df['End'].eq(''), 'End'] = df.groupby('ID')['Start'].shift(-1)
```

Output:

```
   ID     Start       End
0   1   11/1/23   11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23
4   3    9/4/23   9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23
```

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to replace the blank `End` values with `NaN`, and then fill them with the shifted values of `Start` from the same group:

```py
df['End'] = df['End'].replace('', np.nan)
g = df.groupby('ID')
df['End'] = g['End'].fillna(g['Start'].shift(-1))
```

Output:

```
   ID     Start       End
0   1   11/1/23   11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23
4   3    9/4/23   9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23
```

Answer (score 1):

If performance is not a concern, you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Start": ["11/1/23", "11/2/23", "12/12/23", "12/23/23", "9/4/23", "9/11/23"],
    "End": ["", "11/3/23", "12/13/23", "12/28/23", "", "9/18/23"],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Step 1: Get rows with missing end date
empty_end_date_df = df[df["End"] == ""]

for index, row in empty_end_date_df.iterrows():
    # Step 2: Get the other row with the same ID
    same_id_row = df[(df["ID"] == row["ID"]) & (df.index != index)]
    if len(same_id_row) != 1:
        raise ValueError("Should not happen...")

    # Step 3: Update the end date using the start date of the row with the same ID
    df.loc[index, "End"] = same_id_row["Start"].values[0]

print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have sorted rows and missing value can be in next row then you could use `.shift(-1)` to create new column(s) with values from next row.

```
df['next_id']    = df['ID'].shift(-1)
df['next_start'] = df['Start'].shift(-1)
```

```
   ID     Start       End  next_id next_start
0   1   11/1/23                1.0    11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23      2.0   12/12/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23      2.0   12/23/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23      3.0     9/4/23
4   3    9/4/23                3.0    9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23      NaN       None
```

And later you can `apply` function on every row and copy value from `next_start` to `End` when `End` is empty (and when `ID` == `next_id`)

```
def fill_it(row):
    if not row['End'] and row['ID'] == row['next_id']:
        row['End'] = row['next_start']    
    return row
    
df = df.apply(fill_it, axis=1)
```

And later you have to `drop` new columns

```
df.drop(columns=['next_id', 'next_start'], inplace=True)
```

```
   ID     Start       End
0   1   11/1/23   11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23
4   3    9/4/23   9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23
```

---

Full working example

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "ID": [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    "Start": ['11/1/23', '11/2/23', '12/12/23', '12/23/23', '9/4/23', '9/11/23'],
    "End": ['', '11/3/23', '12/13/23', '12/28/23', '','9/18/23']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['next_id']    = df['ID'].shift(-1)
df['next_start'] = df['Start'].shift(-1)

print(df)
print()

def fill_it(row):
    if not row['End'] and row['ID'] == row['next_id']:
        row['End'] = row['next_start']    
    return row
    
df = df.apply(fill_it, axis=1)
df.drop(columns=['next_id', 'next_start'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```

Result:

```
   ID     Start       End  next_id next_start
0   1   11/1/23                1.0    11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23      2.0   12/12/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23      2.0   12/23/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23      3.0     9/4/23
4   3    9/4/23                3.0    9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23      NaN       None

   ID     Start       End
0   1   11/1/23   11/2/23
1   1   11/2/23   11/3/23
2   2  12/12/23  12/13/23
3   2  12/23/23  12/28/23
4   3    9/4/23   9/11/23
5   3   9/11/23   9/18/23
```